# Is there a scheduler for RxJS6 which handles the notification on a WebWorker?

Tags: rxjs6

I have searched the RXJS6 repository, and I have found links going back to RxJS5 and RxJS4 which describe an `asyncScheduler`, but no answer gets right to the point of whether you can process a notification in a WebWorker thus achieving actual parallelization.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to implement a web worker-based scheduler that would work for anything other than the most trivial of cases, as getting a web worker to perform work involves moving both code and data between realms.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the marshaling of code between realms using `URL.createObjectURL(blob);`, as in this code pen: I suspect whether it performs adequately would depend on your use case...
https://codepen.io/deanius/pen/bjVYbm?editors=1111